# JavaScript array sort(function) to sort table rows- not sorting

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I am trying to sort a dynamically constructed table on the client side. So far I have done my research to discover JavaScript's sort() method will take a callback. Here is what I have so far:

```
function retrvCatalog(e){
var merch = document.getElementById('merch');
var tRows = merch.rows;
var tBody = merch.tBodies;
var rowArr = [];
for (x in tRows){
    rowArr[x] = tRows[x];
}
rowArr.sort(function(a, b){
    if (a.cells.textContent < b.cells.textContent){
        return -1;
    }
    if(a.cells.textContent > b.cells.textContent){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
}
```

Stepping through it in Firebug, it appears to not change the order of the rows. Can someone please help me figure out what I am missing?

**FINAL ALGORITHM**

```
function retrvCatalog(e){
var fltr = e.id;
var merch = document.getElementById('merch');
var tblHead = merch.tHead;
merch.deleteTHead();
var tRows = merch.rows;
var rowArr = [];
for (var i=0; i<tRows.length; i++){
    rowArr[i] = tRows[i];
}
rowArr = rowArr.sort(function(a, b){
    if (fltr > 3){
        a = parseFloat(a.cells[fltr].innerHTML);
        b = parseFloat(b.cells[fltr].innerHTML);
    }
    else{
        a = a.cells[fltr].innerHTML;
        b = b.cells[fltr].innerHTML;
    }
    if (a>b){
        return 1;
    }
    if(a<b){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
while(merch.hasChildNodes()) {
    merch.removeChild(merch.firstChild);
}
merch.appendChild(tblHead);
for (i=0;i<rowArr.length;i++){
    merch.appendChild(rowArr[i]);
}
}
```

The final two columns in the row are numbers, so that is why the method to sort is slightly variable.

Comment: If i get this right, the order of the rows is not changed, but the array is sorted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but I'm pretty sure you can't use `textContent` on the `cells` array. You need to index `cells` so you know which column to actually sort on. If your rows have 4 columns each (or even if there's only 1), you still need to tell the sort function which column to sort on.

So in your sort function, if you wanted to sort by the second column, you'd want something like:

```
rowArr.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.cells[1].textContent < b.cells[1].textContent) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a.cells[1].textContent > b.cells[1].textContent) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

And I'm not sure what's in your cells, but you may want to use `.innerHTML`, not `.textContent`.

Answer (score 1):

Several problems in your code.

First, you didn't declare the `x` variable.

```
for(var x...
```

Second, don't use `for-in` to iterate an array like collection. Use `for`.

```
for (var x = 0, len = tRows.length; x < len; x++){
    rowArr[x] = tRows[x];
}
```

Third, there is no `textContent` property of a `cells` collection.

This is easy to test by logging its value. This should have been the first thing you tried.

```
console.log(a.cells.textContent); // undefined
```

You need to decide which cell you want, and ask for it by index.

```
console.log(a.cells[0].textContent);
```

Finally, you should be aware that this technique will not show the result of the sorting in the DOM. You're only sorting the Array. You'll need to append the new ordering to the DOM.

Maybe you knew this, but you didn't show it in your code.

I don't know the relationship of the rows to the tBodies, so I can't give an example. But if all the rows are in one tbody, just loop the Array, and `tBody[0].appendChild(rowArr[i])`

Comment: tRows is not an array, it's an HTML collection. That is why I used "for in"

Comment: Your suggestions were helpful, but didn't answer the question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Declaring the `x` variable isn't necessary, but it does make a global variable named `x` if you don't use `var`. If you look at: http://jsfiddle.net/ex4gV/1/ , you'll see that even though the for loop is scoped in the function, `x` becomes global after its use, but is undefined beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

```
rowArr.sort(function(a,b) {
    a = parseFloat(a.cells.textContent);
    b = parseFloat(b.cells.textContent);
    return (a-b);
};
```

Comment: There's an idea. However, shouldn't it sort alphabetically as well as numerically?

Answer (score -1):

***"don't use for-in to iterate an array like collection."*** - user1673729

*tRows is not an array, it's an HTML collection. That is why I used "for in"* – nodirtyrockstar

An ***HTML Collection*** is an ***array like collection***. Do not use `for-in`.

Comment: This answer does not help me to understand your point. for-in is used for iterating a collection. tRows is a collection I want to iterate.

Comment: @nodirtyrockstar You're right, but look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays